Extracting text using iText7 throws exception
Extracting text from PDF file using iText7 8.0.4
MemoryStream pdfStream = ...
  pdfStream.Position = 0;
  var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
  var reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
  using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
  {
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
  }

throws exception  Error at file pointer 39747  :
     iText.IO.Exceptions.IOException: Error at file pointer 39747.  --->
     iText.IO.Exceptions.IOException: '>' not expected.   
 --- End of inner
     exception stack trace ---    at
     iText.IO.Source.PdfTokenizer.ThrowError(String error, Object[]
     messageParams)    at iText.IO.Source.PdfTokenizer.NextToken()    at
     iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.NextValidToken()  
     at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.ReadObject()   
     at iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util.PdfCanvasParser.Parse(IList`1
     ls)    at
     iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessContent(Byte[]
     contentBytes, PdfResources resources)    at
     iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfCanvasProcessor.ProcessPageContent(PdfPage
     page)    at
     iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
     page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy, IDictionary`2
     additionalContentOperators)    at
     iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(PdfPage
     page, ITextExtractionStrategy strategy)

How to extract text from this PDF ?
PDF is in
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/0a2cb3abb921863f1f7aa109fd58e90e20240522072618/3e3501

I wanted to take a look at that file now but apparently the link has expired. Considering only the stack trace it looks like there is a syntax error in the PDF.

I created new link https://wetransfer.com/downloads/b1dd3a49a2d799a0a5ed7a95c117ebbc20240604071543/96e657   Invoice is sent by supplier and PDF creation cannot changed. Can iText forced to extract text from it or can other .NET Core cross-platform library used for text extraction?

I posted similary question also before for other PDF. In this case liks looks like HARU pdf library created corrupted font table in PDF. How to use iText only for text extraction so that those errors in pdf file are ignored like PDF readers do. Both files were opened correctly in PDF readers and allow text copying.

The issue with the PDF at hand is that an inline image in the page content stream contains the byte sequence that also is used as end-of-inline-image marker. Here the iText parser could indeed be improved not to fall for this false positive.

I can probably download c# source code from GitHub. Which exactly needs changed? Can images removed from pdf before text extraction? Related question is at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78575425/how-to-extract-text-instead-of-question-marks-from-pdf-file

I'm currently very busy. If you haven't found a solution then, you may ping me in a week or so.

I havent found solution. From https://itextpdf.com/start-contributing it looks like it is impossible to submit bug report without pull request and pull requests must be in java. I'm programming in C#.

This issue is caused by an inline image in the PDF page content stream. Its stream data contain the byte sequence of the EI end-of-inline-image marker, making iText prematurely consider this as the end of the inline image. It attempts to interpret the following stream data as content stream instructions which fails with the observed exception.
There are two ways to deal with this, and both require some work.
Improve the iText inline image parsing
Beware, as this approach requires changes in private and/or sealed code, you either have to patch the iText sources and compile your own distribution, or you have to copy substantial parts of the iText content stream parsing framework into your namespaces, improve your copy, and use your code for stream parsing from now an.
The main class of interest here is InlineImageParsingUtils in the iText.Kernel.Pdf.Canvas.Parser.Util namespace. There are two major code locations here to improve:

The ParseSamples method recognizes the end of the inline image data primarily by finding "EI" followed by a white space. Before June 2018, though, it used to look for "EI" surrounded by white spaces.
You may consider rolling back that change and again require the leading white space. The change has been introduced in the commit 0e44a96b2f3b90fb6656310d2c0f5615b05d4391 (which is the autoport from the iText/Java commit e0df12db9cd8869928bbcad7e038f3a5d1aef71c).
Consider, though, that this commit has the title "Fix processing the end of an inline image." and refers to an issue DEVSIX-1914, so quite likely PDFs without a white space before the "EI" marker have been encountered by iText customers resulting in this change.

There is an additional test of the found "EI", the method InlineImageStreamBytesAreComplete is called to check whether the identified stream appears complete, and if this method returns false, ParseSamples continues its search for the correct "EI".
This method checks the stream by applying all declared filters (compression, binary-to-text, ...) and returns false if an exception occurred. Unfortunately, the filter implementations used are mostly built to be error tolerant.
You may consider improving this by creating and applying less error tolerant filter implementations here to increase the likelihood that cut-off streams are recognized. iText already uses a stricter Flate filter here; you can similarly enforce the use of your alternative filter implementations. Furthermore, you can analyze the data you retrieve after applying the filters: Depending on the exact image type (also implied by the filters) you can validate whether the stream represents a complete image.


Either of these improvements would have helped in case of your example PDF: The "EI" iText finds and assumes to be the end of the inline image is not preceded by a white space, and less error tolerant ASCII85Decode and LZWDecode implementations would have identified the incomplete data, as would have an analysis of the size of the the returned data.
Sanitize content streams before parsing
Alternatively, if you don't want to patch or copy the iText content stream parsing code, you can switch to a two-phase approach: In the first phase you can prepare the PDF document by loading all content streams, parsing them with your own code for inline image recognition, removing all the inline images you find, and storing these manipulated streams back into the document; in the second phase you use the regular iText parsing for text extraction.

Where to find sample code in C# which pre-processes pdf? Or is it possible/reasonable to use GhostScript to change pdf, for example remove  images or re-sample them so that iText can process this pdf?

I forwarded the issue to the iText dev team and they created a ticket for it. The priority of that ticket of course depends on customers addressing this as support cases. I don't have finished such pre-processing code
