How to extract text instead of question marks from PDF file
Tying to use iText7 8.0.4 to extract text from pdf file outputs question marks only:
???????? ??????????
?
???????????????????????? ???????????????????
???????? ????????????????????????????
???????????????????????? ????????????????????????????
?????????????? ?????????????????????
???????????? ????????????????????
??????????
????? ??????????
????????????????????? ???????????????????????????????????
????????????? ??????????
????????????????? ??????????????????????????????????
??????? ???????????????? ????????????????
...

In Adobe and Chrome text can copied from pdf properly. How to extract this text in C#
Code used:
MemoryStream pdfStream = ...
  pdfStream.Position = 0;
  var strategy = new LocationTextExtractionStrategy();
  var reader = new PdfReader(pdfStream);
  using var pdfDocument = new PdfDocument(reader);
  for (int i = 1; i <= pdfDocument.GetNumberOfPages(); ++i)
  {
    var page = pdfDocument.GetPage(i);
    var text = PdfTextExtractor.GetTextFromPage(page, strategy);
  }

PDF is at
https://wetransfer.com/downloads/d0c0915f3416b4d9cc735a5b8a36443f20240604123056/c0768c
Answer in
Extract text with iText with embedded fonts
describes that thi may related to custom fonts. However, Adobe PDF reader shows that only Verdana font is used in this PDF.
Tried to convert code from answer Extract text with iText not works: encoding or crypted text? to iText 7 but got lot of errors:

CS0246  The type or namespace name 'PdfStamper' could not be found
CS1061  'PdfReader' does not contain a definition for 'GetPageResources' and no accessible extension method 'GetPageResources' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfReader' could be found
CS1061  'PdfDictionary' does not contain a definition for 'GetAsDict' and no accessible extension method 'GetAsDict' accepting a first argument of type 'PdfDictionary' could be found
CS0117  'PdfName' does not contain a definition for 'FONT'


The ToUnicode maps of your PDF font objects are invalid and don't define any mappings from character codes to Unicode. Thus, a text extractor can only guess (or simply map to the replacement character), and some text extractors may be more lucks in guessing than others.

How to implement automatic text extraction from such files in C# controller in web server? Which text extractor can used or should ghostscript used to pre-process pdfs before passing to iText?
